# Filter classifications above 31

Tags: r, lidr

I am processing a bathymetric lidar dataset, where underwater points are classified as "40". The full las file shows these:

```r
las_all <- readLAS("s08160w08700.las")
unique(las_all$Classification)
#> [1]  1  2  7 18 41 45 40 17  9
```

When I try to filter the .las files to just points classified as 40, I am returned the following error:

```r
las_bathymetric <- readLAS("s08160w08700.las", select = "xyzc", filter = "-keep_class 40")
#> ERROR: '' needs arguments between 0 and 31 but '40' is out of range
#> Error in C_reader(ifiles, ofile, select, filter, filter_wkt) : 
#>  Filter error see message above.
```

Is there a direct way around this? I could reclassify these points in the full dataset to integers < 31, but then this would negate the benefit of reading in just the points I'm interested in.

Comment: Try `-keep_extended_class`. Is you file LAS 1.4? Please edit your post with the output of `print(las_all)`

Comment: -keep_extended_class worked! Thank you! And yes, it is las 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a LAS 1.4 file that allows for more classes than previous standards. You can use `-keep_extended_class` instead of `-keep_class`